# Closed-form of a series relating to sech(*) function

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

Shall we get the closed-form of
$$
S(\gamma) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh[(2n+1)\pi^2/\gamma]}
$$
Any hint?

Comment: Have you any reason to think that a closed form could exist ?

Comment: If the summation were from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, one could express the answer in terms of elliptic functions. For $k=0,\ldots,\infty$, I doubt one can get something reasonable.

Comment: (unless you accept the answer written in terms of $q$-hypergeometric series)

Comment: @Startwearingpurple: So, what's the express when the summation is from -$\infty$ to $\infty$? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contradicting my 1.5-year old comment: for $\Re a>0$, we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh(2n+1)a}=\frac12\left[\vartheta_2\left(0|e^{-2a}\right)\right]^2,$$
where $\vartheta_2(z|q)$ denotes the [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html). For the proof, one may use [this formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.11#E2) and few other identities for elliptic functions.